# How to re-use logical type in Apache Avro

Tags: avro

I can define  UUID type in avro with logical type like this

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"Metadata",
  "namespace":"com.example",
  "doc":"Event metadata",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"messageId",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "logicalType": "uuid"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'd like to re-use UUID someway like this:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"Metadata",
  "namespace":"com.example",
  "doc":"Event metadata",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"messageId",
      "type": "com.example.UUID"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "namespace" : "com.example",
  "name" : "UUID",
  "type": {
    "type": "string",
    "logicalType": "uuid"
  }
}
```

But this schema is not valid. How can I re-use logical type in Avro?